# Android Fit Picture into ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, scaling

I currently have a layout in which there is a button and when the button is selected, the user is prompted to choose a picture from his gallery. When the picture is chosen, I am trying to fit the picture into the entire imageview. However, the picture doesn't fit into the imageview. Is there a way that I can maybe edit the length/height of the picture that the user selects or a way in which I can make the picture fit into the ImageView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it either programmatically or in XML:

Programmatically:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

XML:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```